# XML file from AutoCad 2011

Tags: javascript, xml, html, autocad

We have a simple autocad 2011 .dwg file which is used as a floor plan for a trade show.  All booths are drawn in with lines in one layer, a text layer is used to put in booth numbers, and a third text layer is used for company names.

It seems as if exporting all of the coordinates would be simple, but is obviously beyond my capabilities (I'm a web developer, not a seasoned Autocad user).  The end result desired is to build an interactive map using javascript and html, but the most important part, which is to get the points so that I can build the map, is eluding me.

If you have any suggestions or directions I would greatly appreciate hearing them.

Comment: I should mention that we have a custom command that exports the map to pdf, connects to server via ftp, and uploads it.  I envision it automatically creating an xml file and then uploading it then a script will handle regeneration of the dynamic floor plan

Answer (score 2):

Look for an API that you can use to get data out of a dwg file. Here is one:  http://www.opendesign.com/the_oda_platform/TD

Apparently it can also be used to convert dwg to svg format which can be displayed in most web browsers.  Using svg would be a lot easier than writing your own script to generate the plan.